# Rails Gem packaging causing uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to package a small module I wrote for Rails into a gem. Currently residing at github, whenever I install the gem and attempt to use it I get an error:

```
uninitialized constant Foundation::FormBuilder
```

But the correct scope is `Foundation::FormBuilder::Rails::FormBuilder`, and I can't figure out what is going wrong. Does it have something to do with having `Rails` as a module?

I'm lost trying to work out what the error is - the package works if I put the source in my application helpers directory, so I'm really wondering if there is an issue with my gemspec or `lib/` structure. Can someone please provide advice?

[Source on GitHub](https://github.com/ashleybye/foundation-formbuilder-rails/tree/develop)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I had been a typo in my require path. As always, it pays to check and re-check `require` statements. And if in doubt, check again before posting online!